# Snakemake Ambiguity between 2 rules with similar output file type

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I am trying to map 3 samples: SRR14724459, SRR14724473, and a combination of both SRR14724459_SRR14724473.
I have 2 rules that share a similar file type output (.bam), and even tho I am naming their wildcards different, I still get an ambiguity error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
AmbiguousRuleException:
Rules map_hybrid and map are ambiguous for the file /gpfs/scratch/hpadre/snakemake_outputs/mapped_dir/SRR14724459_SRR14724473__0.9.bam.
Expected input files:
        map_hybrid: /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_SRR14724473_0.9/SRR14724459_R1_trimmed_SRR14724473_R1_trimmed_0.9.fastq /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_SRR14724473_0.9/SRR14724459_R2_trimmed_SRR14724473_R2_trimmed_0.9.fastq
        map: /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_SRR14724473__0.9/SRR14724459_SRR14724473__0.9_R1_trimmed.fastq /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_SRR14724473__0.9/SRR14724459_SRR14724473__0.9_R2_trimmed.fastq
```

From my Snakefile, here are my variables:

```
all_samples:  ['SRR14724459', 'SRR14724473']
sample1: ['SRR14724459']
sample2: ['SRR14724473']
titration:[0.9]
```

This is my rule all:

```
rule all:
    expand(MAPPED_DIR + "/{sample}.bam", sample=all_samples),
    expand(MAPPED_DIR + "/{sample1}_{sample2}_{titration}.bam", zip, sample1=list_a_titrations, sample2=list_b_titrations, titration=tit_list)
```

This is my map rule:

```
rule map:
    input:
        r1 = TRIMMED_DIR + "/{sample}/{sample}_R1_trimmed.fastq",
        r2 = TRIMMED_DIR + "/{sample}/{sample}_R2_trimmed.fastq"
    output:
        MAPPED_DIR + "/{sample}.bam"
    threads: 28
    params:
        genome = HUMAN_GENOME_DIR
    log:
        LOG_DIR + "/map/{sample}_map.log"
    benchmark:
        BENCHMARK_DIR + "/map/{sample}_bwa_benchmark.txt"
    wildcard_constraints:
        word='[^0-9]*'
    shell:
        """
        bwa mem -t {threads} {params.genome} {input.r1} {input.r2} 2> {log} | samtools view -hSbo > {output}
        """
```

This is my map_hybrid:

```
rule map_hybrid:
    input:
        r1 = TRIMMED_DIR + "/{sample1}_{sample2}_{titration}/{sample1}_R1_trimmed_{sample2}_R1_trimmed_{titration}.fastq",
        r2 = TRIMMED_DIR + "/{sample1}_{sample2}_{titration}/{sample1}_R2_trimmed_{sample2}_R2_trimmed_{titration}.fastq"
    output:
        MAPPED_DIR + "/{sample1}_{sample2}_{titration}.bam"
    threads: 28
    params:
        genome = HUMAN_GENOME_DIR
    log:
        LOG_DIR + "/map/{sample1}_{sample2}_{titration}_map.log"
    benchmark:
        BENCHMARK_DIR + "/map/{sample1}_{sample2}_{titration}_bwa_benchmark.txt"
    shell:
        """
        set +e
        bwa mem -t {threads} {params.genome} {input.r1} {input.r2} 2> {log} | samtools view -hSbo > {output}
        exitcode=$?
        if [ $exitcode -eq 1 ]
        then
            exit 1
        else
            exit 0
        fi
        """
```

The expected input files SHOULD BE as so:

```
Expected input files:
        map_hybrid: /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_SRR14724473_0.9/SRR14724459_R1_trimmed_SRR14724473_R1_trimmed_0.9.fastq /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_SRR14724473_0.9/SRR14724459_R2_trimmed_SRR14724473_R2_trimmed_0.9.fastq
        map: /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_R1_trimmed.fastq /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724459_R2_trimmed.fastq

and also

/home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724473_R1_trimmed.fastq /home/hpadre/ngs_artifacts_proj/output_directories/trimmed_dir/SRR14724473_R2_trimmed.fastq
```

Comment: It is easier for people to understand your question and try to reproduce your problem if you post a working, ideally minimum, working example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules `map` and `map_hybrid` can both produce your desired files, for `snakemake` they are [ambigious rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#handling-ambiguous-rules).
The names of the wildcards is irrelevant, what is relevant is whether the wildcards in both rules can match the same output filepath.

That is the case here.

While `rule map_hybrid` can produce the output file `SRR14724459_R2_trimmed_SRR14724473_R2_trimmed_0.9.fastq` where the wildcard matches are

```
sample1=SRR14724459
sample2=SRR14724473
```

the `rule map` can also produce this output with the wildcard match

```
sample=SRR14724459_R2_trimmed_SRR14724473
```

To prevent ambiguity you can use the `wildcard_constraint`, so that the `{sample}` wildcard only matches strings starting with `SRR` followed by numbers:

```
sample='SRR\d+'
```

Integrated into your `rule map`:

```py
rule map:
    input:
        r1 = TRIMMED_DIR + "/{sample}/{sample}_R1_trimmed.fastq",
        r2 = TRIMMED_DIR + "/{sample}/{sample}_R2_trimmed.fastq"
    output:
        MAPPED_DIR + "/{sample}.bam"
    threads: 28
    params:
        genome = HUMAN_GENOME_DIR
    log:
        LOG_DIR + "/map/{sample}_map.log"
    benchmark:
        BENCHMARK_DIR + "/map/{sample}_bwa_benchmark.txt"
    wildcard_constraints:
        word='[^0-9]*',
        sample='SRR\d+'
    shell:
        """
        bwa mem -t {threads} {params.genome} {input.r1} {input.r2} 2> {log} | samtools view -hSbo > {output}
        """
```

it should resolve the ambiguity.